# Get specific characters in a string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string which can vary :

```
String filePath = "/this/is/my/file.txt";
```

I need to get this string to other strings that information :

```
"/this/is/my" and "file.txt"
```

I tried this method but it failed(crash) :

```
    int counter = 0;
    filePath = "/this/is/my/file.txt";
    String filePath2 = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); // return "file.txt"
    for (int i = 0; i < filePath2.length(); i++) {
        counter++; // count number of char on filePath2
    }
    String filePath3 = filePath3.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("") + counter); // Remove "file.txt" from filePath2 depending of character numbers on filePath2 backwards
```

Anyone know a better method? Thanks!

```
12-05 15:53:00.940  11102-11102/br.fwax.paulo.flasher E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.fwax.paulo.flasher, PID: 11102
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.fwax.paulo.flasher/br.fwax.paulo.flasher.MFlasher}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=21; index=29
```

Comment: Try: `String filePath3 = filePath.replace(filePath2, "");` - So to get the original (full path) - the file.

Comment: how about String filePath3 = filePath.substring(0,filePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Java's `File` class?

```
File f = new File(filePath);
String directory = f.getParent();
String fileName = f.getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you even have your for loop?

```
int index = filePath.lastIndexOf("/");
String firstString = filePath.substring(0, index);
String secondString = filePath.substring(index+1, filePath.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File` class.

```
String filePath = "/this/is/my/file.txt";

File f = new File(filePath);

System.out.println(f.getParent());// \this\is\my
System.out.println(f.getName());// file.txt
```

Note that this can change `/` to `\` but if you are going to use this results as arguments in other API related to files there shouldn't be any problems with this change.